# Dlookup in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables one is the host_sku table the other is the channel table.

I have a concatenation key set up in both tables.

I am trying to fill the channel_table.SSK with the data in the Host_Sku_table.SSK where the two concatenation keys match.

**Host_Sku_Table:
id,
Sku,
Material Description(concatenation key),
SSK**

**Channel_Table:
id,
Sku,
LookupKey(Concatenation Key),
SSK**

this is what i have tried and nothing is working!

DLookUp([Host_Sku_Table]![SSK],[Host_Sku_Table],[Channel_Table]![LookUpKey]=[Host_Sku_Table]![Material Description])

can anyone help

I also tried an IIF( containing a dlookup) that didnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all cases the first two arguments to [DLookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) are simple strings denoting the field to return and the domain (table) to search. I think you want something more like this

```vbs
DLookUp("SSK","Host_Sku_Table","[Material Description]='" & [Channel_Table]![LookUpKey] & "'")
```